# Output Text Doesn't Show in Correct Format

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Here is the JavaScript I use to animate slider (fade effect) of the content I read from database:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    var terms = ["span_1","span_2"];
    var i = 0;

    function rotateTerm() {
        jQuery("#text-content").fadeOut(200, function() {
          jQuery(this).text(jQuery('#text-slider .'+terms[i]).html()+i).fadeIn(200);
        });
        jQuery("#title-content").fadeOut(200, function() {
          jQuery(this).text(jQuery('#title-slider .'+terms[i]).html()+i).fadeIn(200);
           i == terms.length - 1 ? i=0 : i++;
        });
    }
    rotateTerm();
    setInterval(rotateTerm, 1000);   
});
</script>
```

And here is the PHP code I use:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($testLst)) :     
        $num=1; 
        foreach($testLst as $key=>$item):
             $item->slug = $item->id;
             $item->catslug = $item->catid ;

?><div id="hidden-content" style="display:none;">       
    <div id="title-slider"> 
        <span class="<?php echo 'span_'.$num; ?>">
            <h4><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id, $item->catid)); ?>">
                <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
            </h4>
        </span>
    </div>
<div id="text-slider">
    <span class="<?php echo 'span_'.$num; ?>">
        <p>
            <?php
                $concat=array_slice(explode(' ',$item->introtext),0,20);
                $concat=implode(' ',$concat);
                echo $concat."...";
            ?>
        </p>
    </span>
</div></div>
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id, $item->catid)); ?>" title="Learn more" class="learnMore">Learn more &gt;&gt;</a></p>
<?php
    $num++;
    endforeach;
    endif;
?>

<div id="title-content">
</div>
<div id="text-content">
</div>
```

And [here is a JSFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/A5smV/) reproducing what I would like to do.

My problem is that I am getting data that still has HTML tags, however I would like the output to have my CSS styles.

Comment: Can you add stylesheets also ?

Comment: I think that is irrelevant, the style sheet is a large file

the output i receive is added with tags `<h4>..<p></p><a href=...>`

the content I would like to get is correct though

Comment: You mean you want to add same style class as you spans ?

Comment: Thanks I'll do that later if I have time

Comment: No, I was asking you. Do you want to add same css class as the `<span>` tags?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am trying to add something like that too.

Comment: very hard to format this question.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the node, and set that to be the new content of the target elements, to keep everything in jQuery objects, but personally, I'd use the `.outerHTML` property.

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5smV/2/) to show you what I mean: I've changed the `.text(...set content here)` to `.html()`, because we're injecting HTML content. Then, I added `[0]` at the end of your selector, to return the *raw* element reference, which gives access to all standard JS properties and methods an element has, and just went ahead and fetched the `outerHTML`... easy-peasy